# Measures of association, Concordant and Discordant

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

I want to calculate concordant and discordant pairs on nx2 tables.

---

```
|    Value1   |  Value2  |
|_____________|__________|
|    0.3434   | 1        |
|    0.2132   | 2        |
|    0.3      | 3.3245   |
|    0.6      | 0.12321  |
|    0.745234 | 523      |
|    4        | 0.2134   |
|    3        | 111      |
|    .        | .        |
|    .        | .        |
|    .        | .        |
|    .        | .        |
|    .        | .        |
|_____________|__________|
```

This is a n x 2 table. How can I calculate concordant and discordant pairs? I am sorry I can't find suitable question tag.

Comment: Are you sure your question is about _Mathematica_?

Comment: I have a document about this problem, you can see
[link]http://uregina.ca/~gingrich/gamma.pdf

But this is not suitable for me... I can't understand. I found a lot of document about this topic, some of them calculate different the others.

Answer (score 8):

```
SeedRandom[123];
data = 5 + RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 20];

TableForm[data,TableHeadings->{Range@Length@data,{"value1", "value2"}}]//Style[#, 16] &
```

[image]

**Concordant and discordant pairs:**

From the documentation on `KendallTau`

[image]

Generalizing @eldo's post we can get the concordant and discordant pairs of observations as follows:

```
cdpairsF = With[{pairs = Tuples[#, 2]}, 
          Pick[pairs, Sign /@ (Times @@ Subtract @@ # & /@ pairs), #] & /@ {1, -1}] &;
{concordantpairs, discordantpairs} = cdpairsF[data];
```

Example:

```
MatrixPlot[
  Partition[Sign[Times @@ Subtract @@ #] & /@ Tuples[data, 2], Length[data]], 
  ColorRules -> {-1 -> Red, 1 -> Green, 0 -> Blue}, 
  Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Thick],
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Red, Green}, {"concordant", "discordant"}]]
```

[image]

Example: Observations concordant/discordant with a reference observation:

```
SeedRandom[123];
data = 5 + RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 100];
{concordantpairs, discordantpairs} = cdpairsF[data];
options = {PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red}, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],
           Frame -> True, 
           FrameLabel -> {Style["value1", 14], Style["value2", 14], None, None},
           PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8}}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, 
           ImagePadding -> 40};

Manipulate[With[{cp = Select[concordantpairs, #[[1]] == data[[k]] &],
                  dp = Select[discordantpairs, #[[1]] == data[[k]] &]},
  ListPlot[{data,
            If[# == {}, ## &[], #[[All, 2]]] &@cp,
            If[# == {}, ## &[], #[[All, 2]]] &@dp},
   GridLines -> List /@ data[[k]], options,
   PlotLegends ->
     PointLegend[{Blue, Green, Red},
            {Style[StringForm["data[[``]] = ``", k, Round[data[[k]], 0.01]], 
                  Blue, 16],
             Style[StringForm["`` points \n concordant with data[[``]]",Length[cp], k], 
                  Green, 16], 
             Style[StringForm["`` points \n discordant with data[[``]]",Length[dp], k],
                  Red, 16]}, 
            LegendMarkers -> Graphics[Disk[]]]]],
   {{k, 1}, 1, Length[data], 1}, ContentSize -> {750, 450}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

**Measures of Association:**

With Version 9.0.1.0 we have the following measures of association:

[KendallTau](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KendallTau.html)

[SpearmanRho](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SpearmanRho.html)

[BlomqvistBeta](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlomqvistBeta.html)

[GoodmanKruskalGamma](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GoodmanKruskalGamma.html)

[HoeffdingD](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoeffdingD.html)

```
{#, # @@ Transpose@data} & /@ 
     {KendallTau, SpearmanRho, BlomqvistBeta, GoodmanKruskalGamma, HoeffdingD} 
             //  TableForm // Style[#, 20] &
```

[image]

Comment: I searched so much. But if the table 2xn I didn't find anything :(

Comment: @user3646666, hope the post and the links are useful. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: I don't think so. Thanks.

Comment: @user3646666, please note that the data you posted is `nx2` (n rows 2 columns); so is the data in my example.

Comment: ohh you are right , sorry. It has to be n rows and 2 columns.. nx2 table. I will edit the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {{{1, 1}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}};

Times @@@ (Sign /@ Subtract @@@ m) /. (0 | 1) -> "Concordant" /. -1 -> "Discordant"
```

> {"Concordant", "Discordant", "Concordant"}

Comment: I couldn't understand anything :( sorry. Can you explain this with mathematics ?